# Stop execution of a recusive function that reads a JSON object with two nested object types

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have a JSON object built from two nested objects, both of which have a `label` property. My function checks that, for a given rank n, the array of `QuestionModel[]` or `ResponseModel[]` does not have equal labels.

```
type ResponseModel = {
    label: string;
    questions?: QuestionModel[];
};

export type QuestionModel = {
    label: string;
    responses?: ResponseModel[];
};

const duplicatedLabel = async (data: QuestionModel[] | ResponseModel[]) => {
    const labelSet = new Set<string>();
    for (let obj of data) {
        if (labelSet.has(obj.label)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            labelSet.add(obj.label);
        }

        if ("questions" in obj) return await duplicatedLabel(obj.questions!);
        if ("responses" in obj) return await duplicatedLabel(obj.responses!);
    }
    return false;
};
```

For example, this JSON document is poorly constructed, with two equal labels at the same level `yes`. The function should return `true`, but it doesn't.

```
[
    {
        "label": "your destination?",
        "responses": [
            {
                "label": "USA",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "label": "do you have a visa?",
                        "responses": [
                            {
                                "label": "yes",
                                "questions": [
                                   {
                                       "label":"Are you sure"
                                   }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "yes",
                                "questions": [
                                   {
                                       "label":"It's your last decision?"
                                   }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "Canada",
                "questions": [
                    {
                        "label": "do you have a work licence?",
                        "responses": [
                            {
                            "label": "yes"
                            },
                            {
                            "label": "no"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The function always returns `false`

Comment: When I run your function with that dataset I get true - https://jsfiddle.net/ej8gymp6/

Comment: That's because equal labels come last. I have modified the data variable, [look at the result](https://jsfiddle.net/ys3qhjmr/)

Comment: You're creating new `labelSet` sets with each recursive function call. All the tracked labels are essentially ignored with each recursive call. I suspect you need to add the `labelSet`-so-far to each recursive call.

Comment: You only want to return within the loop if the value is true.  See https://jsfiddle.net/mz5u4o9p/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach works, thank you

```
type ResponseModel = {
    label: string;
    questions?: QuestionModel[];
};

export type QuestionModel = {
    label: string;
    responses?: ResponseModel[];
};

const duplicatedLabel = async (data: QuestionModel[] | ResponseModel[]) => {
    const labelSet = new Set<string>();
    for (let obj of data) {
        if (labelSet.has(obj.label)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            labelSet.add(obj.label);
        }

        let subDupe;

        if ("questions" in obj) subDupe = await duplicatedLabel(obj.questions!);
        if ("responses" in obj) subDupe = await duplicatedLabel(obj.responses!);

        if (subDupe) return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```